# Adding Apache 2.4.52 to repository

Tags: upgrade, repository, apache2.4

How to install Apache 2.4.52 in Ubuntu 21.10?

Comment: Most packages are fixed for any given release.

Comment: Who moved the question is wrong because :

a) it doesn't resolve the problem.
b) and all the solutions explained in the other answer is lots of blah-blah that solves nothing and explains the "politics" behind the updates (and something about freeze that happened years ago).

Comment: Why has this been closed? The linked question has nothing to with this one. This question asks how to install latest version of Apache. The linked question asks why it isn't there. That's a different question and its answers do not help with this one in the slightest.

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself risky and adventurere, then try [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2?field.series_filter=impish) to get *2.4.52-2+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1*:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```